Expand $f(z) = \frac{z-\sin z}{z}$ when $0<|z|<\infty$ as Laurent series?
$$f(z)=\frac{z-\sin z}{z},  0<|z|<\infty $$
Trying to solve it:
So $f(z)$ contains $\sin z$, so I think I should use this $$\sin z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
then
$$f(z)=\frac{z-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}{z}=1-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}{z}$$
So I end up here and it just doesn't look the best...
okay, let's try making it better:
$$
f(z)=1-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}z^{1}}{(2n+1)!}}{z}=1-{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}
\\
=1+(-1){\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}
\\
=1+{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}
$$
$$=1+(-1)^{0+1}\frac{z^{2*0}}{(2*0+1)!}+{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}$$
$$=1+(-1)^{1}\frac{z^{0}}{(1)!}+{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}$$
$$=1+(-1)+{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}$$
$$={\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}$$
My only question here is does it satisfy $0<|z|<\infty$?

Just pull 1 from the exponent in the second summand.

@MatchaLatte the ring and f(z) is different. That didn't help.

You can start summing from $n=1$ because $1-(-1)^0\frac{z^{2\cdot 0}}{(2\cdot 0+1)!}=0$ and include the minus sign into $(-1)^{n+1}$. What's wrong with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$?

@MatchaLatte how did you got rid of 1?

Dude, just write it down on paper...

Why aren't you satisfied with the last expression?

@MatchaLatte I did! Is it correct? Also, does it satisfy the condition?

@md2perpe it looks not tidy, I wanted to get just a sum

As in the link above, $z=0$ is a removable singularity, so the Laurent series is just Maclaurin series in this case. And so you are correct @Baltics

Thank you all very much for helping me with this problem!!

As suggest comments use that :
$$ \dfrac{z-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{z}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(n+1)!} $$
Which gives the Laurent Series development around $0$ :
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^{k}$$
with
$$ a_0=0$$
$$ a_{2k+1}=0$$
$$ a_{2k}=\dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{(k+1)!} $$

so it satisfies the condition 0<|z|<∞ ? I am sorry for asking, I am just confused and lost.

Yes. You can verify it by applying basic convergence test on the resulting series for a given $0<|z| <\infty$ or simply stating that because the initial Laurent series of $\sin(z)$ around zero point worked over $0<|z|<\infty$ it works for the resulting series (since we only introduce the quotient by $z\neq 0$ in initial expression)

thank you very much for helping me!!!

You're welcomed
